# Unexpected Whitespace in Source Code Viewer

Tags: php, html, whitespace

Using if and echo statements in the code below is causing a blank whitespace to appear *(on line 4 in this instance)* when viewing my website's source using Google Chrome:

[image]

```
<ul>
<li>Hi</li>
<li>Hello</li>
<?php 
if($something) {
   echo'
   <li>1</li>
   <li>2</li>
   ';
}else{
   echo'
   <li>2</li>
   <li>1</li>
   ';
}
?>
</ul>
```

Comment: Don't you see a newline after `echo'`?

Comment: `echo'<li>1</li><li>2</li>';`?

Comment: @TheCodesee  you have answers below, please check.Mark and up-vote one as answer. up-vote others if they are useful too. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The very first character after the ' is a new line.

```
echo'
   <li>1</li>
   <li>2</li>
   ';
```

This should get rid of it:

```
echo'<li>1</li>
   <li>2</li>
   ';
```

Comment: @TheCodesee There's really no point in keeping the source code as clean as possible. What's really important is what is rendered.

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because of the new line that you are putting in your echo statement combined with the fact that there is a newline after your `<li>Hello</li>` line. You can either put your opening `<?php` on the same line as `<li>Hello</li>` or you can remove the newline from the echo statement